# Is there a function or method for decoding OPC-UA extension objects to readable form

Tags: python, opc-ua, extension-objects

UaExpert is displaying this array as follows:

[image]

Is there any way to decode this extension object to a readable form?  My output is the following.  I done some research and the question has been raised but I haven't found any examples.  Using the dict function gets you part way there but some of the items are returned as bytes.

```
{'TypeId': NumericNodeId(ns=2;i=543214), 'Encoding': 1, 'Body': b'\x1b\x00\x00\x00External Application Closed\x13\x00\x00\x0025/01/2023 12:40:56\x05\x00\x00\x00dfius\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '_freeze': True}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the type definition with the following method:

```
await client.load_type_definitions()
```

The complete Sample can be found here:

- Server: [Sever with Structs](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/server-custom-structures-before-1.04.py)
- Client: [Client reading Structs](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client_read-custom_structures.py)